# Sitecore Index Update on Item Delete

Tags: solr

Is there a way where i can delete the Item from Sitecore Solr Index when an Item is deleted since item is not there i can not get the handle of item

Comment: What is your index updated strategy set to? Deleting an item in the Content Editor should automatically update the index if you have the right update strategies set. There is no reason at all to manually remove or add documents in the index.

Comment: I have got OnPublishEndAsync which Triggers an incremental updating of index on end of any publish activity but not sure how delete of an Item automatically triggers Index rebuild Am i missing any setting over here

Comment: The item will be removed from the web database during a publish. At the end of that publish, the index will be updated.

Comment: Indexes are not getting updated automatically when an Item is deleted

Comment: Is this happening on CD or CM?

Comment: This is  on CD are we missing something in configration while applying the OnPublishEndAsync  and i wonder how OnPublishEndAsync will work for item delete since there is no nothing to publish as item to publish has already been deleted

Comment: @user2332873 you have to publish the parent item of the deleted item to changes to take effect on web database. Once you publish the parent item, the deleted item should be removed from the CD index.

Comment: Update the web db then index would be updated.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what scFootsteps mentioned about publishing the parent folder/item so that the web database gets updated, Make sure that you also have to set a distinct InstanceName in ScalabilitySettings.config for each CD and CM server.
Make sure that EventQueue is working as expected, When you delete an item and publish the parent, you should see 2 entries in event queue table, one for CM server and one for CD server, as each server needs to acknowledge that it processed the event of deleting an item.